# Linux Search and replace in specific section

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a set of configuration files, that we want to automate the installation for
The files contains sections describing modules like so:

```
[section 1]
enable = no
...
...
[Section 2]
enable = no
...
...
```

So from my bash script I want to first look for the [section] and then find the first orcurrance of enable in that section and change it to yes.

I have been looking at sed to do this but I can't figure out how to get it to only change Section 2 and not section 1 (the configuration files can contain 20-30 sections all containing a line with enable = no)

I tried looking af grep to first search for the sektion heading, counting line numbers, and then use sed to search and replace from the linenumber greb returns.

It got very complicated and diddent work.

Any one have a good idea on how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking to a fixed string `Section` of `section` between `[]`, or can that be any string like `[server 6]` ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The sections can be called anything but they all start with a heading that is marked with [ ] So the section headings could be [Coffee] [Candy] or [Server 6]

Comment: Look at the `vi` instead. Something like `vi -c "/^[|^[" -c "/enable = no" -c "s/enable = no/enable = yes" -c "x" yourfile` where `/^[|^[` - find second bracket at the line beginning, `/enable = no` - find forward the line containing `enable = no` string, `s/enable = no/enable = yes` - replace (substitute), `x` - save & exit.

Answer (score -1):

An ugly solution that will only replace the first `enable =` line in a section is based on a reasonable approach.
Make sure that each section is on his own line. When that has been done, you can change the first `enable=` on that line.
You can convert the sections to one line by changing the newlines by a marker (I will use `\r`).
You don't want one long line, so put each new section on a new line, by changing the `[` into a newline. After the `sed` replacement you restore the `[` and the newlines.

```
tr '\n[' '\r\n' < inputfile |
   sed '/^Section 2\]/ s/enable = [^\r]*/enable = yes/' | 
   tr '\n\r' '[\n'
```

This solution has a bug: After the `tr` the last line is missing an `\n`, causing `sed` to ignore that line in the search for sections.
I didn't find a nice way to fix this, so I would love comments how I can improve the following ugly fix:

```
(tr '\n[' '\r\n' < inputfile ; echo) | 
   sed '/^Section 2\]/ s/enable = [^\r]*/enable = yes/;$ s/$-1/\r/' |
   tr '\n\r' '[\n' | sed '$ d'
```